# Strongly continuous semigroup Kolmogorov forward integral equation

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $\{ P_t \}_{t \geq 0}$ be a SCSF($\mathcal{S}$) (strongly continuous semigroup on $\mathcal{S}$) on the space $(E,\mathcal{E})$, where $E$ is a Polish space, equipped with the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{E}$, and $\mathcal{S}$ is the Banach space of functions $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, equipped with the norm $|| \cdot ||$. Now denote $A$ as the generator and $\mathcal{D}(A)$ as the associated domain. Suppose that $||P_t|| \leq e^{\alpha t}$ for some $\alpha \geq 0$.

I now want to show the following time-version of the Kolmogorov forward integral equation: For any $d \in \mathbb{R}$, $t\geq 0$ and $f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$,
$$ e^{dt} P_t f = f + \int_0^t e^{du} \left[ P_u(Af)(x) + d P_u f \right] du, \quad x \in E.$$

Furthermore it is said that this implies that there is no function $f \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ such that $A f = \lambda f$ for some $\lambda > \alpha$. This in return implies that $\mathcal{D}(A)$ does not contain eigenfunctions to non-negative eigenvalues $\lambda > \alpha$. But I really have no idea how I could prove these two things. Could anyone help me? Thanks for any assistance.

I did notice that $\{ P_t e^{-\alpha t} \}_{t \geq 0}$ defines a SCCSG($\mathcal{S}$) (contracting property). Hence we can express the generator of $\{ P_t e^{- \alpha t}\}_{t \geq 0}$ in terms of the generator $A$ of $P_t$ which has domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$. Does this help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the integral equation, note:

$$\int_0^t e^{du} [P_u(Af)(x)+dP_uf]du=\int_0^t \frac{d}{du}[(e^{du})(P_u f)]du=e^{dt}P_tf-e^0P_0f=e^{dt}P_tf-f$$, where the last equation is due to the reqularity of $t \mapsto P_tf$. (i.e. it is differentiable).

Hence $$\int_0^t e^{du} [P_u(Af)(x)+dP_uf]du+f=e^{dt}P_tf, \, \forall_{d \in \mathbb{R}}, \, \forall_{t \geq0}, \, x \in D(A)$$.

Now, for your second question: take in the above equation $d=-\lambda$.

Then $$\int_0^t e^{-\lambda u} [P_u(Af)(x)-\lambda P_uf]du+f=e^{-\lambda t}P_tf \, \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\int_0^t e^{-\lambda u}[P_u(\lambda f)(x)-\lambda P_uf]du+f= e^{-\lambda t}P_tf \, \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\int_0^t e^{-\lambda u}[(\lambda-\lambda) P_uf] du+f=f=e^{-\lambda t}P_tf \, \Leftrightarrow$$

Hence $f = e^{-\lambda t}P_tf$ and thus $e^{-\lambda t}P_t = Identity$. Which implies that the norm of $P_t$ is larger that $e^{at}$, since $\lambda>\alpha$, which is a contradiction.

I hope this helps..

Comment: Can you explain why the first equality is true?

Comment: Yes, I will work out the derivative. $\frac{d}{du}[(e^{du})(P_uf)]=[\frac{d}{du}(e^{du})]P_uf+e^{du}[\frac{d}{du}(P_uf)]$, by the product rule. Then, the first term is easy to differentiate, for the second term we use $\frac{d}{du}P_uf=AP_uf$. Then we get  $\frac{d}{du}[(e^{du})(P_uf)]=de^{du}P_uf+e^{du}A(P_uf)$. Also we can interchange the $P_u$ and the $A$ by properties of the generator, and we have the result.